# how to use two versions of glibc simultaneously?

Tags: glibc

hi,
I am currently using ubuntu 9.10 with the glibc version 2.11.1-0,
well i am doing a project, that i want to test with the another version of glibc that is 2.5-58, i wanted to know following things regarding this:

How to compile the version of 2.5-58, however keeping the previous version?

How to link the existing programs with the binaries of newer version of glibc?

I would be highly obliged if anybody can help me!!!

Let me know if my question is not specific. Please it wud be really helpful if anybody can answer me.
Thanks

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-use-older-versions-of-glibc-189174/ may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix glibc versions installed in your system. Especially don't mix programs linked against one or the other version. You will most probably break your system if you do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert at this stuff, but maybe this will help.

http://www.bitwagon.com/rtldi/rtldi.html

Comment: Please don't post just links. They will eventually become broken and does not help those in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There no solution in ubuntu:

http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/14774

There is "portage" to manage multiple version's libary in Gentoo:

http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=1

Comment: Please don't post just links. They will eventually become broken and does not help those in the future.